# pass the value to shell script

Tags: shell, parameters, scripting

```
export c_db1=oraclenod1  
export c_db2=oraclenod2
```

When I am running below :

```
perl $dboh/clone/bin/clone.pl ORACLE_HOME="$dboh" ORACLE_HOME_NAME="${db_upper}_ORACLE_HOME" ORACLE_BASE="${dboh_base}"  '-O"CLUSTER_NODES={"${c_db1}","${c_db2}"}"'
```

I am getting below :

```
./runInstaller -clone -waitForCompletion  "ORACLE_HOME=/u01/oracle/dba/product/11.2.0.3" "ORACLE_HOME_NAME=DBA_ORACLE_HOME" "ORACLE_BASE=/u01/oracle/dba/product" "CLUSTER_NODES={"${c_db1}","${c_db2}"}" -silent -noConfig -nowait
```

I have tried to pass c_db1 and c_db2 , can any1 help to let me know how I can pass this ?

Appreciate any help

Thanks,      SM

Comment: When I am running below :      

perl $dboh/clone/bin/clone.pl ORACLE_HOME="$dboh" ORACLE_HOME_NAME="${db_upper}_ORACLE_HOME" ORACLE_BASE="${dboh_base}"  '-O"CLUSTER_NODES={\"${c_db1}",\"${c_db2}"}"'        

I am getting below :        

./runInstaller -clone -waitForCompletion  "ORACLE_HOME=/u01/oracle/dba/product/11.2.0.3" "ORACLE_HOME_NAME=DBA_ORACLE_HOME" "ORACLE_BASE=/u01/oracle/dba/product" "CLUSTER_NODES={\"${c_db1}",\"${c_db2}"}" -silent -noConfig -nowait

Comment: Thanks TartanLlama for editing my post .

Answer (score 0):

You're using sijngle quotes for the last argument

```
'-O"CLUSTER_NODES={"${c_db1}","${c_db2}"}"'
```

Single quotes prevent variable expansion: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting

Assuming you need those literal quotes, do this

```
"-O\"CLUSTER_NODES={\"${c_db1}\",\"${c_db2}\"}\""
```

Based on your comment, you don't need *all* the interior quotes, so

```
"-O\"CLUSTER_NODES={${c_db1},${c_db2}}\""
```

Comment: Thanks for your update , still I am having same problem variable is not going to CLUSTER_NODES

Comment: Let me clear more it    I need like below :     '-O"CLUSTER_NODES={oraclenod1,oraclenod2}"'  using scripts ..

Comment: When I passed like below :       perl $dboh/clone/bin/clone.pl ORACLE_HOME="$dboh" ORACLE_HOME_NAME="${db_upper}_ORACLE_HOME" ORACLE_BASE="${dboh_base}"  '-O\"CLUSTER_NODES={${c_db1},${c_db2}}\""'
     Logfile is showing like    CLUSTER_NODES must be specified within {}!

Comment: We can't guess what your code does. What does clone.pl do with the arguments it receives?